# Dropdown positioning for this mat-select in Angular

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using `Angular 15.1.3`, `Angular Material 14.0.4` and `Angular CDK 14.0.4`

I am able to position the panel of the Dropdown just below or above the Dropdown Textbox.

This is the code I have used for `mat-select`

```
<mat-select (selectionChange)="securityQuestionChange($event)" placeholder="Select and Answer 3 Security Questions" [disabled]="sqSelected.length === 3 || isRegistrationSuccess" panelClass="custom-panel-sec-questions">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let sq of securityQuestions" [value]="sq.value">
        {{ sq.question }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

But when I use the below code in `styles.scss`, it is not working as other Dropdowns..

```
.custom-panel-sec-questions {
  margin: 60px 0px !important;
}
```

Below is the screenshot of the style it applied..

[image: Security Questions]

Could not figure out where it is going wrong...

Comment: Figured out something. In the above screenshot of `.mat-select-panel`, if I add as `margin: 60px 0px` then the panel is actually moving as expected. So, where should I add this code snippet for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your css with the below code:

Replace HTML code like this :

```
<div class="select-container">
<mat-select (selectionChange)="securityQuestionChange($event)" placeholder="Select and Answer 3 Security Questions" [disabled]="sqSelected.length === 3 || isRegistrationSuccess" panelClass="custom-panel-sec-questions">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let sq of securityQuestions" [value]="sq.value">
        {{ sq.question }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
</div>
```

Apply CSS :

```
.select-container{
  margin: 60px 0px;
}
```

I just wrapped the select inside a div and applied CSS to that class.

Try this.

Comment: No. It does not work.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz and share here

Comment: I am not comfortable in creating Stackblitz. But trying my best to create..

Comment: Okay, no worries. Firstly, maintain the angular versions in sync. This might be the issue sometimes. Secondly can you give more details as it is hard to identify from these details.

Comment: I tried adding the relevant versions of the libraries and added the code for dropdown. But it is not appearing in the output window. This is the URL - https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-tmg46a. Please make the dropdown visible. I will try to replicate afterwards. Sorry for that.

Comment: Hi @Bhavy-Ladani - Did you figure out something?

Comment: Ah sorry, it is hard to figure out things like this.I will create my own project and will update you if I can make this work.

Comment: Just I want to confirm one thing from you. If the panel is moving as expected, then I want  to know where I should write that `margin` css code...

Comment: I edited my answer. Please try that

Answer (score 0):

```
:host {
 ::ng-deep {
  .custom-panel-sec-questions {
    margin: 60px 0px !important;
   }
 }
}
```

Try this one - So basically put `ng-deep` inside the `:host` to isolate it's style. Do let me know if this works for you ?

If above solution is not working. check this

> Then i have created for you [stackblitz you can see the working example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-17-file-upload-mp2mz7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Happy coding! Cheers

Comment: Still it is not working..

Comment: @CPK_2011 I have updated the solution in the code snippet for you. 